# Saving filename in a specific format in Python

Tags: python, txt

I am generating numbers in a specific range with a specific stepsize and saving to a `.txt` file. But I want to save the filename in a specific format. I present the current and expected output.

```
Start=0
End=500001
Stepsize=1000
for i in range(Start,End,Stepsize):
    #print(i)
    
    with open('All_values_{Start}_{End}_{Stepsize}.txt', 'a') as f:
        #writer = csv.writer(f)   
        #print(" =",i)
        f.writelines('\n')
        f.write(str(i))
```

The current output in terms of file naming is

```
All_values_{Start}_{End}_{Stepsize}
```

The expected output is

```
All_values_0_500001_1000
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String formatting: % vs. .format vs. f-string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format-vs-f-string-literal)

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap the file name in a "f-string" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use f-strings, just add an `f` to this line:

```py
    with open(f'All_values_{Start}_{End}_{Stepsize}.txt', 'a') as f:
```